# How to add ARCore dependency type com.google.ar.core to AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to upload my AR application to the Google Play Console and am getting errors with each attempt. The application is built in `Unity` with `ARCore` using gradle. I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to edit my `AndroidManifest.xml` but I think I am doing something wrong.

Initially I was trying to build an APK with split application binary in Unity, but was only allowed to export a `.gradle` file. So I've opened this in Android Studio and built an APK and AAB to upload to the Google Play Console.

The AAB file upload yielded this error:

> The ARCore dependency type com.google.ar.core is missing from the
>   AndroidManifest.xml file although the meta-data tag
>   com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version has been specified.

I tried adding `implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.12.0'` to the AndroidManifest dependencies, but the gradle project sync fails.

Do I need to edit the manifest further?

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:
I have added the ARCore dependency in the gradle file and have tagged AR core in the manifest.

This is the `.gradle` file:

```js
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }



    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.12.0'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'UnityARCore', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityChannel', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'arcore_client', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'nativeshare-release', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'unityandroidpermissions', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'unitygar', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        applicationId 'com.TylerCalkin.OURARhug'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '2.4'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/x86/*.so'
    }


}
```

I'm now getting

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version@value value=(190805000) from [com.google.ar:core:1.12.0] AndroidManifest.xml:35:13-38
>       is also present at [:arcore_client:] AndroidManifest.xml:43:13-38 value=(180525000).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-35:41 to override.

but my Merged Manifest tab lists only one Manifest Source and some Other Manifest Files not contributing any elements. I am trying to add

> tools:replace="android:value"

But I can only find a single manifest in my project, and adding it yields additional errors when I try to build an APK.

Can anyone direct me to exactly where and how to fix my merge conflict?

For example when I add it to my manifest like this:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Name.Appname" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round" >
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.Name.Appname.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.tango-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="92706e04-4de4-49cc-a450-6e2e2712e07a" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
    <meta-data tools:replace="android:value" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

I get these errors:

```js
java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
 at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:558)
 at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessApplicationManifest.java:208)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor516.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
 at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
 at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

UPDATE #2: I have tried adding tools:replace at various places in the manifest, application, and meta-data tags, and none of them work. I've seen solutions in other questions but none of the answers I have found are fixing my errors.

Comment: Hi there and congratulations on your first SO question! :) I'm not really an untity specialist, but have you tried following this instruction: https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/arcore-with-vuforia.html?

Comment: Thank you for the link! While I'm not using Vuforia that article is quite helpful. I'm still getting an error, but this is a nice reference :)

Answer (score 6):

The dependency of ARCore goes in the gradle file. You request that dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.11.0'
}
```

Do you have the ARCore tag in your manifest?

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There are already 2 dependencies references in the gradle file:  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    } .... and one with several implementations. Should it go in one of them, or should I use a third?

Comment: When I add the ARCore tag to the manifest I get this error: Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version@value value=(190805000) from [com.google.ar:core:1.12.0] AndroidManifest.xml:35:13-38
 is also present at [:arcore_client:] AndroidManifest.xml:43:13-38 value=(180525000).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-35:41 to override.

Comment: The problem is in your manifest. Are you using multiple libraries? Are you using multiple modules in your app? Are you familiar with manifest mergers? Basically the modules, and libraries in your project also have a manifest file. When you try to build the app the manifest files get combined. You need to carefully look at what is getting merged to fix the manifest problem of the ARCore app. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: Thank you for the link. I only have one module, so I might be using multiple libraries without knowing it. My Merged Manifest tab lists only one Manifest Source and some Other Manifest Files not contributing any elements, then the merging error. I'm stuck now trying to find this other manifest file or library.

Comment: Can you post your Gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I've had added the gradle file to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue! Getting Build failed due to merge conflict. Solved it by following 2 steps:

STEP1:

> Copy AndroidManifest.xml file from
> {ProjectPath}\Temp\gradleOut\src\main to
> {ProjectPath}\Assets\Plugins\Android

STEP2:

Copy below line in application tag with other meta-data tags

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" tools:replace="android:value" />
```

STEP3:

Try to build and run it again! Hopefully, it will work.